# Ignore a junit test with parametrized test

Tags: testing, junit

I run parametrized test with Junit, but I want to skip some tests following a flag. The parameters are stored in a CSV file and when a flag is "off" I want to skip this test. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Assume](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assume.html) class.

```
@Test
public void something() throws Exception {
    Assume.assumeFalse(valueFromCsv.equals("off"));
}
```

The test will be skipped by JUnit if the assumption is not fulfilled.